# Texas expansion: Military

Tags: internal-consistency, alternate-history, military

## Alternate Timeline

So let's say that there is a dragged out War of 1812 that splits the north and south. Southerners moving west will be moving into Texas. There is thus more manpower in Texas and so the Texan Revolution is more successful. Not that it wouldn't be successful because even if Texas lost 1 revolution, there would be a second Texan Revolution which Texas would be more likely to win.

This attracts even more settlers to Texas. Something like the Mexican American War would still happen but because of Manifest Destiny, Texas would reach the California coast first. The British would at least want to integrate Seattle Bay into Canada. Something like this would happen as far as territory:

[image]

Texas would be on the opposite side of the USA in WWII. It would be on the side of the Axis powers and destroy the USA. The allies might still win WWII but Texas will have destroyed the USA. Then Texas does the arduous task of integrating the territory it defeated in WWII. Then it would look like this:

[image]

## Question

How big would the Texan military have to be for this to occur? Would Texas have to inherit the military in the South?

EDIT:
Texas goes to war against the US during WWII. I don't think it would matter much what year of WWII Texas went to war as long as the Texan-American war ends before or when WWII ends which is in the year 1945.

Comment: It's certainly an interesting question, as it would fundamentally change the way some parts of WWII worked - one huge advantage that the Allies had was to use the US as a giant factory out of harm's way, unlike the Axis powers. Having an enemy in North America complicates the US's war considerably, especially with that size border. One very important clarification needed though - _when_ does Texas go to war with the US?

Comment: You stretch the plausibility too much for me. In the census of 1850, Texas population was less than 1% of the USA at the time. There is not much they could have done to play a significant role.

Comment: Texas (in yellow) would go to war against the rest of the USA? What has Mexico been doing all that time?

Comment: What kind of regime is Texas during WW2 (to be on the side of the Axis ) ?  This has a massive influence on how difficult or easy it would be for Texas to take over what seem like the confederacy and  the core northern states.  A fascist regime would be unwelcome, a strongly anti-British one might do better.  What is Canada doing while this happens ?

Comment: You'd have to explain why Southerners would move west in Texas faster than they did historically. Also, with a weakened US there's no reason why the British bother with the 1818 Oregon Treaty and simply claim and occupy the Oregon Territory, which gives them modern day Washington, Oregon, Idaho, and chunks of Montana and Wyoming. For that matter, there's no reason the rest of the border goes south of the 49th parallel. Here is a more likely example of what an American loss (which a split would result in) would look like: https://www.alternatehistory.com/forum/attachments/cs-png.58302/

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to answer this question, in particular regarding who Southern forces side with, until you address the history of slavery in your alternate history.  You're asking about a hypothetical war that pits one half of the US against the other; it only makes sense to draw parallels with the biggest case of this actually happening: the Civil War.  In b4 "Civil War wasn't about slavery": many Northerners may have had non-altruistic reasons for opposing slavery, but in the end that was the issue that divided the country at the time.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps about 51% of US forces that actually fought in WWII in the real world? i.e. about 8 million men, 50,000 tanks, 125,000 artillery pieces, 150,000 aircraft, 5 battleships, 50 aircraft carriers, 400 destroyers, frigates, or cruisers, 125 submarines, about 50 billion $$ worth of munitions would a start.

It is very unlikely that the rest of the US would ignore the enemy right by the doorstep and send military supplies and forces elsewhere, after all.